# How can I sent some data (may be a json data) from Express backend to React client through response header?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I'm using the github oauth to authenticate user,so during the setup I used redirect route as my backend url (eg :http://localhost:4000/home).

After getting the token to that route,I perform a http request to url
(https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&code=${requestToken})
In order to get the access token of user.

My question is after I receive this access token,I pass this to front-end just as a parameter in url(which is visible to user).
Eg: res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/home/${accessToken}`)

So I just want to make it invisible to  user by passing it through response header. How can I do this????

```
// Declare the redirect route
app.get('/home', (req, res) => {

  // The req.query object has the query params that
  // were sent to this route. We want the `code` param

  const requestToken = req.query.code

  axios({

    // make a POST request
    method: 'post',

    // To the Github authentication API, with the client ID, client secret and request token
    url: `https://github.com/login/oauth/access_token?client_id=${clientID}&client_secret=${clientSecret}&code=${requestToken}`,

    // Set the content type header, so that we get the response in JSON
    headers: {
         accept: 'application/json'
    }

  }).then((response) => {

    // Once we get the response, extract the access token from the response body
    const accessToken = response.data.access_token

    // redirect the user to the welcome page, along with the access token
    res.redirect(`http://localhost:3000/home/${accessToken}`)

  })
})
```

Comment: why not use session to store token?

Comment: Even though I do like that, at the very first interaction from back-end to front-end token will be visible....., I want to make token invisible from very first interaction.

Comment: Normally, if I'm requesting from front-end to back-end then I will be able to make token invisible. But in this scenario from front_end request is made to GitOAuth, and then GitOAuth redirect to my back-end